# Kendo Rich Text Editor initial font

Tags: kendo-ui

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/Eh6X2/19/) I have a Kendo rich text editor. When the user starts writing text, I need the font to be Arial 12pt. How to accomplish that?

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script after you initialize the editor

```
var editorBody = $(".k-editable-area iframe").contents().find("body");

editorBody.css("font-family", "Arial");
editorBody.css("font-size", "12pt");
```

Or if you have multiple editor and you want to modify by using its ID, you can do this also

```
var editorBody1 = $($("#editor1").getKendoEditor().body);

editorBody1.css("font-family" ,"Arial");
editorBody1.css("font-size", "12pt");
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct advance answer:

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
editor.body.style.fontFamily = "Lato,";
```

also try this option:

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
editor.body.style.font = "500 14px/1.2 Lato, Arial, sans-serif";
```